# retrieve rows where they are unique with condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello I have no idea to ask this question,
I have model Transaction that contains the amount the operator of the transaction, for example

| Amount | Operator | Transaction ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | add | 1234 |
| 100 | sub | 1234 |
| 333 | sub | 1235 |
| 555 | sub | 1236 |
| 444 | sub | 1237 |

I want to retrieve using eloquent the transaction with operator "sub" but not "add" so I want to retrieve only these records

| Amount | Operator | Transaction ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 333 | sub | 1235 |
| 555 | sub | 1236 |
| 444 | sub | 1237 |

Comment: how is the condition Amount `100`??

Comment: amount is just exampleI don't want to get records that are exist both sub and add

Answer (score 3):

you can do this :-

```
Transaction::where('operator','sub')
           ->whereNotIn('transaction_id', function($query) {
                $query->select('transaction_id')
                      ->from('transactions')
                      ->where('operator','add'); 
            })->get();
```

Comment: be sure your column name is Operator or operator

Comment: I want to retrieve records that has the operator sub and not add, this will retrieve everything with condition sub

Comment: sorry , mis understanding from me , 
you can do this by using sub query like this :-

Transaction::where('operator','sub')->whereNotIn('transaction_id', function($query) {
 query->select('transaction_id')->from('transactions')->where('operator','add');
})->get()

try this and told me the result

Comment: I am getting empty results
I am trying with   
->groupBy('transaction_id')
 ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) < 2') but still nothing

Comment: can you show to me the query that give you empty array  ?